# Hide/cancel the "No data sources are configured to run this SQL" message in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I could not find any way to hide this warning in Intellij:

> No data sources are configured to run this SQL and provide advanced code assistance

[image]

What is the magic combination of settings to make this go *poof*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not appear to be any setting that actually works.  Instead it's actually pretty easy to create a "fake" `sql` source.

- Click on *Configure data source* link in upper right
- Select "SQL" (generic one)
- Don't worry about the (bogus) connection parameters: just go ahead and "Save" it

The fake connection will not cause issues and now the SQL will be parsed and that message goes .. *poof* !